# Terrafrom EMR Bootstrap Shell File

Tags: terraform, amazon-emr

I wish to execute a shell file inside a Terrafrom module for AWS EMR, passing the file to the bootstrap action. However the file is not loading.

The code block to call the file is is in the  main.tf file seen here -

```
bootstrap_action {
  path = "${file("files/emr_bootstrap.sh")}"
  name = "emr_bootstrap"
}
```

And main.tf is on the same level as the "files" directory.

The error message is -

```
ValidationException: Invalid bootstrap action path, must be a location in Amazon S3 or a local path starting with 'file:'.
```

Any ideas / pointer would be much appreciated.

## Reply to answer 1

Thank you HenryTK. I've also tried this without success, so I think the issue is the file doesn't actually exist in the destination. To overcome this before the bootstrap_action block, a file copy block as seen here was added -

```
provisioner "file" {
  source = "files/emr_bootstrap.sh"
  destination = "/tmp/emr_bootstrap.sh"
}
```

Even with this file provisioner, the shell script is not getting executed, which implies the bootstrap_action is not finding the shell script.

Answer (score 0):

Use the magic `path.module` interpolation[1].

```
bootstrap_action {
  path = "${file("${path.module}/files/emr_bootstrap.sh")}"
  name = "emr_bootstrap"
}
```

[1] https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html

Comment: Can you confirm this works? I tried this and I got an error that looked like this:

`Invalid bootstrap action path, must be a location in Amazon S3 or a local path starting with 'file:'`

Answer (score 0):

so with s3 you do it like:

```
  bootstrap_action {
path = "s3://${var.bucket_name}/bootstrap/configure-system.sh"
name = "configure_system"
```

}

i'd guess locally you would want it like:

```
  bootstrap_action {
path = "file://<path>"
name = "configure_system"
```

}

let me know if this helped

Answer (score 0):

The script referred in `bootstrap_action` should be either be kept on S3 or be local **to the instances in the cluster**, but not to Terraform's local filesystem.

That way you can use something like the following snippet but apparently can't upload local scripts that way:

```
bootstrap_action {
  name = "openjdk11"
  path = "file:/usr/bin/sudo"
  args = ["amazon-linux-extras", "install", "java-openjdk11", "-y"]
}
```

I could not find any references to that except for a single example on Github but you can easily verify the behaviour yourself.

As for your original intent for providing the script with Terraform you'll probably have to upload it to S3 in some different way or wrap it to a single command like the above if it is a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to copy file to a master node and execute it there after the cluster has been created. Can be core instances as well. Not sure it can be called bootstrap action though...

```
    resource "null_resource" "your_action_name" {
    
      triggers = {
        private_ip = data.aws_instance.master.private_ip
      }
    
      connection {
        type = "ssh"
        user = "ec2-user"
        host = data.aws_instance.master.private_ip
      }
    
      provisioner "file" {
        when        = create
        source      = "${path.module}/emr_bootstrap.sh"
        destination = "/tmp/emr_bootstrap.sh"
    
      }
    
      provisioner "remote-exec" {
        when = create
        inline = [
          "chmod +x /tmp/emr_bootstrap.sh",
          "/tmp/emr_bootstrap.sh"
        ]
      }
    }
```

Add appropriate ssh authentication, if needed.

In data.tf you need to add:

```
    data "aws_instance" "master" {
      filter {
        name   = "dns-name"
        values = aws_emr_cluster.your_clister_name.*.master_public_dns
      }
    }
```